# google-sign DEVELOPER ERROR when generating release version in expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, google-oauth

I've been seeing a lot of solutions but none of them seemed to work in my case
using the comand npx expo run:android and it's working.
But when I use Eas-cli to build a APK version it just stop working and I am trying to figure out why this is happening

Things I already tried:

1. Generate and regenerate SHA1 key from android folder
2. Use google Oauth2.0 cloud and Firebase (both returned the same error in the same case)
3. add support email to both plataforms
4. Use GoogleSignin.configure() empty

node:
v16.15.1

expo:
6.3.10

react-native:
0.72.5

trying to figure out why this is happening and how to make my google login work in release/production build.